# Move rows between tables in SQL

Tags: sql, partitioning

I have 2 tables, an active table and an inactive table. I want to *move* rows from the active to the inactive table. My first thought was

```
insert into inactive select * from active where ...
delete from active active where ...
```

However about .42 seconds later I noticed this will drop/duplicate rows if updates alter what the where clause selects.

In this case, I can easily prevent that but what should I do in cases where I can't?

edit: From the answers it look like there isn't an easy/trivial way to do this. I'm really surprised by this. I would think that there would be some substantial benefits to having it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Status flags are your friend.

```
UPDATE old_data SET move="MARKED";
INSERT INTO somewhere... SELECT where move="MARKED";
DELETE FROM old_data WHERE move="MARKED";
```

If you do this with Autocommit off, it will seize locks all over the place.

You can COMMIT after each step, if you want to do a little less locking.

Comment: It seems you need FTS3 for this? I got `Error: no such module: FTS3`. I cannot find a sqlite3 binary for Android with FTS3...

Answer (score 4):

(In MS SQL at least) you could use transactions and locking hints:

```
begin tran

insert into inactive
select * from active with (updlock)
where ...

delete from active
where ...

commit tran
```

Without locking hint (updlock) deadlocks may occur, if someone does alter records being deleted.

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about sqlite, but I get `Error: near "(": syntax error
`

Comment: @LuisA.Florit - where did I say 'sqlite'? My advice will work in MS SQL Server, most likely are there some similar possibilities in Oracle and other sql servers, but syntax may vary. SQLite has somewhat reduced functionality; does it support transactions and query hints, I don't know. From your comment I would say that hints are not supported.

Answer (score 4):

Does your database support the OUTPUT Clause? Then this could be a perfect and easy to follow solution for you, couldn't it?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

```
delete active with (readpast)
output DELETED.*
into inactive
where ...
```

Comment: I'll have to check, but if it does, that is EXACTLY what I was looking for!! (MySQL in case someone gets to it before I do.)

Comment: What about triggers? In SQL Server I have done a similar task with a trigger on delete that inserted the deleted posts in a history table.

Answer (score 1):

If you can lock the rows pessimistically, that is as you read them to copy them into the inactive table, then no one can change them out from under you.

The method to lock the rows varies by database brand, and you don't specify that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a local table var and put the values into there, insert them into your inactive table, then delete the rows from the active table that are in your local list.

The transaction idea works just as well though too.

Answer (score 1):

Either use a unique id column like

```
delete from active where rowid in (select rowid in inactive)
```

or

```
delete from active as a 
where exists (select * 
              from inactive 
              where pkfld1=a.pkfld1 
              and pkfld2=a.pkfld2)
```

Also, don't forget to wrap this process in a transaction.

Good luck.

Comment: EXISTS isn't entirely MS SQL Server specific - it's SQL-92 standard and I believe it's on MySQL and Oracle as well (somebody correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: hmmm ... it looks like you are correct.  http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt

Answer (score 0):

This is how I preserve my where clauses:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
  TheKey int PRIMARY KEY
)
--
INSERT INTO @MyTable(TheKey)
SELECT TheKey FROM SourceTable WHERE rows I want
--
INSERT INTO Inactive(fieldlist)
SELECT fieldlist
FROM Active
WHERE TheKey IN (SELECT TheKey FROM @MyTable)
--
DELETE
FROM Active
WHERE TheKey IN (SELECT TheKey FROM @MyTable)
```

If you need stronger than this, you'll need to look at locking (block out changes during the transaction).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have two tables, rather than a column for "IsActive"?

Comment: Table size related performance. IIRC that alone can be a good reason, In my cases because of the way I'm using it, if a query does anything /but/ an index lookup, it /will/ turn into a worst cases lookup (kind of like here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probing)

Comment: Also: "I'll never be using this code again so why fix what mostly works" ;-)

Comment: OK, agreed. Now we're discussing one of the consequences. Another is the inevitable "find the records WHERE ..." and they might be in either table.

A reasonable question might be "is this turning out to be the best way to deal with table size related perf issues?" That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Is the table so megahuge that SQL Server is actually unable to store and retrieve on the indexes efficiently enough? The question as presented doesn't suggest that level of sophisticated understanding of the technology.